# Get json value from array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looping through my `achievements` props to display a series of divs:

```
const listItems = this.props.todo.achievements.map((achievement) =>
  <div className="cell" key={achievement.id}>
     {achievements[achievement.id].label}
  </div>
);`
```

How can I pull the label out of a json I'm importing from a local file?

```
{
 "achievements":[
  {
     "label":"one",
     "id":0
  },
  {
     "label":"two",
     "id":1
  },
  {
     "label":"three",
     "id":2
  },
  {
     "label":"four",
     "id":3
  },
  {
     "label":"five",
     "id":4
  }]
 }
```

In my root reducer I have my initial state which stores the achievement `id`.

If I output `{achievement}`, I only get the number. Should I set my intital state to store the label, rather than store it in a local json file?

```
const initialState = [
  {
    date: "Fri 1st",
    enjoyments: [1,2,3],
    achievements: [1,3,2],
    id: 0
  },
  {
    date: "Fri 2",
    enjoyments: [1,3,2],
    achievements: [1,3,2],
    id: 1
  },
```

Comment: Like @felix said, you should have access to the label property in the map callback, just wanted to point out that the "achievements" array is currently a typo in your json => "achievementa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`achievement` is already one of the objects in the array. You just have to access its `label` property:

```
{achievement.label}
```

---

Have a look at the following posts to learn more about JSON and objects (they are not the same):

- [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)
- [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/218196)

Comment: I can only get the id not the label, do I need to change my json?